# JavaFX: Gif и пауза

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, sleep

Идея такая:
есть скрытая GIF'ка. при нажатии на кнопку, она становится видимой, пауза в пару секунд, GIF'ка опять становится невидимой и происходит изменения в окне.
Пытался это сделать - во время паузы не работает гиф (не видно, что она появляется и исчезает).
решил сделать через поток след образом:

```
    shar_img_gif.setVisible(true);
    Thread s1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                shar_img_gif.setVisible(false);
                int i = (int)(Math.random()*o.x);
                shar_otv1.setText(o.otv[i]);
                shar_vopros.setText(shar_text.getText()+"?");
                shar_text.setText(null);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    s1.start();
```

но начинает ругаться на 2 эти строки:

```
shar_otv1.setText(o.otv[i]);
shar_vopros.setText(shar_text.getText()+"?");
```

если вынести их за пределы потока - все будет работать, но не так как надо (выполняется сразу, а надо чтобы этот кусок работал после паузы, когда GIF'ка исчезнет).

эти 2 строки не хотят работать просто в потоке. 
как это исправить? и почему так происходит?

Comment: Изменения в gui должны происходить в FX потоке. Оберните методы контролов на которые вылетает исклчение в Platform.runLater(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Timer:

```
shar_img_gif.setVisible(true);
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000/*Time in millis*/,e->
{
    Platform.runLater(()->
    {
        shar_img_gif.setVisible(false);
        int i = (int)(Math.random()*o.x);
        shar_otv1.setText(o.otv[i]);
        shar_vopros.setText(shar_text.getText()+"?");
        shar_text.setText(null);
    }/*Runnable*/);
}/*ActionListener*/);
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Исключение появляется так, как работа с JavaFX должна проиводиться в JavaFX потоке, для этого нужно использовать

```
Platform.runLater(()->
{
    //Your code there
});
```

`()->{}` - это лямбда выражение, добавленное в java 8, оно заменяет `new Runnable(){}`

Comment: ваш пример незаработал, но разобрался с Platform.runLater. спасибо!

Comment: Прошу прощения, вместо Timer написал Thread (Возможно не работает из-за этого)